# Which access method shall be used for a Berkeley DB that it is going to store 15.000.000 of integer keys?

Tags: key-value, berkeley-db

I am planning to evaluate BerkeleyDB for a project where I have to store 15.000.000 of key/value pairs.

Keys are integers of 10 digits.
Values are variable lenght binary data.

In the BerkeleyDB documentation (https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs276a/projects/docs/berkeleydb/ref/am_conf/intro.html) it is said that there are four access methods that can be configured:

1. Btree
2. Hash
3. Queue
4. Recno

While the documentation describes each access method, I can not fully understand which access method would fit better for this specific data set I need to store.

Which access method shall be used for this kind of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When unsure, choose btree.  It's the most flexible access method.  Sure, if you're positive that your application fits in one of the other ones, go for it.

A note of caution: writing an application using BDB that really works, that's transactional, recoverable, and offers consistency guarantees is going to be time consuming and prone to error at every step.  And, if you're using this for commercial purposes, the licensing could be a total dealbreaker.  For some things, it's really the best option.  Just make sure you weigh all the other key value store options before embarking on your BDB quest:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-value_database

Comment: Thanks for the note of caution. According to your experience, which would be an easy alternative to be used with Java. My datamodel is really simple, as described, integers (they are actually timestamps) as keys and variable length binary payload (50-100 bytes) as values. No concurrency, just one thread writing the values, and another few ones reading. Not a lot of writting activity either.

Comment: That whole dataset is on the order of a couple of gigabytes?  I'd keep it all in memory in whatever Java datastructure makes sense.  Log the writes to files in the filesystem.  Maybe just append them to a flat file?  On startup, read in the whole thing and apply the logged writes in order.

Comment: For a more traditional database, look at LMDB.  It has Java bindings.  Should be much easier to get going with than Berkeley DB!

Comment: Thanks I will have a look onto it. BTW Reading "The Berkey DB Book", and if I understood it correctly, the only access method which allows variable-length values (payloads) is RECNO

Comment: Btree definitely permits variable length data.  The access method section of the book could be clearer there.  I believe hash does also, but it can be more of a problem there due to the walking.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. After reading the chapter 11 of the book with the Java API examples I also realized that. The access method chapter was a bit misleading because the only method were it is explicitly said that allows variable length payloads is recno. I will initially give Berkeley DB a try because of its Java API (I am prototyping in Java). Having the book also helps to get the stuff done.

Comment: I tried both Berkeley DB and Kyoto Cabinet. Berkeley DB was fantastic but I found complex to operate it (it gives mutex errors and stuff that you do not know how to handle). License is also problematic as you point, as it unclear (and hence risky) if the source code must be liberated or not. Kyoto Cabinet is super simple (the API is extremely simple), but it does not handle concurrency. I am going for LMDB, worse API than Kyoto.